# Удаление динамического списка паскаль

Tags: pascal

Всем привет, не могу понять в чем дело, почему программа падает

Есть двусвязный динамичный список. элемент[значение, ссылка на предыдущий элемент, ссылка на следующий элемент].

Крайние элементы указывают на nil.

Пытаюсь удалить, но вываливает "инвалид поинтер".

Функции прокомментированы, думаю будет ясно.

Вот сама процедура удаления( есть общая процедура удаления узла + процедуры для удаления первого элемента, второго элемента и произвольного по ссылке)

Дело в том, что при освобождении памяти от последнего оставшегося элемента в списке сразу вылетает ошибка, я никак не могу понять, в чем дело.

```
procedure DelNode(var atmp:TTList);
var tmp:TTList;
begin
tmp:=nil;
if (atmp.pnext=nil)and(atmp.pprev=nil)then
begin
  dispose(atmp);
  atmp:=nil;
end
else begin
  if (atmp.pnext<>nil)and(atmp.pprev<>nil)then
    begin
      atmp.PPrev.PNext:=atmp.PNext;
      atmp.PNext.PPrev:=atmp.PPrev;
      atmp:=atmp.pnext;
      dispose(atmp);
      exit;
    end;
  if atmp.pprev=nil then
    begin
      atmp:=atmp.PNext;
      dispose(atmp.pprev);
      atmp.pprev:=nil;
      exit;
    end;
  if atmp.pnext=nil then
    begin
      atmp:=atmp.Pprev;
      dispose(atmp.pnext);
      atmp.pnext:=nil;
      exit;
    end;
end;
end;

(*Удаление текущего элемента, указатель перемещается на следующий.*)
procedure DelByRef(var aList : TTList);
begin
  if aList<>nil then DelNode(aList);
end;

(*Удаление элемента в начале списка.*)
procedure DelF(var aList : TTList);
var tmp:TTList;
begin
  if aList<>nil then
  begin
    if (aList.pprev=nil)and(aList.pnext=nil) then begin dispose(aList);aList:=nil; exit;end;

    tmp:=GetFirst(aList);
    if tmp.PNext=nil then begin tmp:=nil;DelNode(aList);end
    else DelNode(tmp);
  end;
end;

(*Удаление элемента в конце списка.*)
procedure DelL(var aList : TTList); 
var tmp:TTList;
begin
  if aList<>nil then
  begin
  if (aList.pprev=nil)and(aList.pnext=nil) then begin dispose(aList);aList:=nil; exit;end;
    tmp:=GetLast(aList);
    if tmp.PPrev=nil then
    begin
      tmp:=nil;
      DelNode(aList);
    end
    else DelNode(tmp);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем столько процедур ради удаления одного элемента ?

`procedure DelNode(var aList: TTLits);
begin
  if (aList != nil) begin (* если элемент пустой, то удалять нечего *)
    if (aList.pprev != nil) begin (* сохраняем связь предыдущего элемента с последующим *)
        aList.pperv.pnext = aList.pnext;
    end;
    if (aList.pnext != nil) begin (* сохраняем связь последующего элемента с предыдущим *)
        aList.pnext.pprev = aList.pprev;
    end;
    dispose(alist)
  end (* if (aList != nil) *);
end (* DelNode *);`

Comment: <> - не равно  
:= - присваивание

Comment: Только чтобы не потерять ссылку на список(к нему можно обратиться только через aList), нужно ещё пару строк. Мб кому ещё понадобится  
  
procedure DelNode(var aList: TTList);  
var tmp:TTList;  
begin  
if (aList <> nil) then  
  begin   
  tmp:=nil;    
  if aList.pprev <> nil then  
    begin  
      aList.pprev.pnext := aList.pnext;  
      tmp:=aList.PPrev;  
    end;  
  if (aList.pnext <> nil) then  
    begin     
      aList.pnext.pprev := aList.pprev;  
      tmp:=aList.Pnext;  
    end;  
  dispose(alist);  
  aList:=tmp;  
  end;  
end;